# Como montar um dicionário a partir de dois arrays, um de chaves e outro de valores em swift

Tags: array, swift, dicionário

Tenho dois `arrays` contendo informações de quadras e jogadores. Preciso colocar em uma `tableview` estes dados, sendo que as seções da tabela seriam as quadras e os valores, de cada seção, seriam os jogadores. As seções pode ter 2 ou 4 linhas cada. Isso vai depender do que estiver selecionado em um `segmetedControl`.

1. arrayQuadra: String
2. arrayJogador: String

Pensei em criar um dicionário `[String: [String]]` mas não estou sabendo popular este dicionário.

Answer (score 0):

Seria mais conveniente, você criar um dado estruturado primeiro para compor essa sua tabela, porque assim fica fácil de você estruturar e editar seus dados quando necessário.

Depois, sempre que você for usar seções e celulas de uma `UITableView`, é melhor você **sempre**  usar uma array bidimensional, em vez de um dicionário.

Vou te dar um exemplo bem simples, de como essa estrutura ficaria para o seu caso, de qualquer forma, ela é simples o suficiente para praticamente qualquer outro caso onde você precise usar sections e cells.

Primeiro veja essas structs:

```
struct Section {
    var title: String = ""
    var items: [ SectionItem ] = []
}

struct SectionItem {
    var name: String = ""
    var value: String = "Some Value"
}
```

Elas simplesmente servem para estruturar os dados que você precisa exibir na tela, isso te ajuda a organizar melhor seu código, da mais flexibilidade para alterações futuras e também há outras vantagens que não precisam ser citadas agora mas que talvez você perceba com o tempo.

Ok, agora com os dados estruturados e pronto para serem carregados, você já pode usar essa estrutura para compor uma `UITableView` de forma bem simples.

Considere a implementação a seguir:

```
struct ViewModel {
    var sections: [ Section ] = [] // Preencha essa array da forma que quiser
}

class ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var viewModel = ViewModel()

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return viewModel.sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.sections[ section ].items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return viewModel.sections[ section ].title
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomeIdentifier")!
        let data = viewModel.sections[ indexPath.section ].items[ indexPath.row ]

        cell.textLabel?.text = data.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.value

        return cell
    }
}
```

Se você fosse usar um `Dictionary`, provavelmente você teria que mapear os dados para pegar o indice certo, da forma acima, você pega o dado para a seção e a celula com seu respectivo indice, porque você fornece exatamente a quantidade de seções e celulas que você precisa.

Bom espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi. Sou novo em Swift. Eu tenho 2 informações: `arrayJogador: [String]` e `arrayQuadra: [String]`. Na tua proposta tem `title`, `items`,`name`, `value`. As seções estão no `arrayQuadra` e as linhas das seções estão em `arrayJogador`.

Comment: Na minha proposta, você vai usar uma `struct` pra definir tudo relacionado a os dados da sessão da tabela, `title` por exemplo, seria o nome que aparece na seção, vc pode adicionar quantos quiser, porque sua sessão agora é uma struct. `items` é uma array dos elementos que preenchem as celulas de cada sessão, sendo ele também uma `struct`, vc vai ter mais controle da informação e vai ter um código mais legível também. Tente fazer com um exemplo isolado primeiro, é a melhor coisa pra entender esse approach.